# Spring - Is there a way to enable transaction management in application.properties?

Tags: java, spring, transactions, entitymanager

I have found two ways of enabling transaction management in Spring according to https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/EnableTransactionManagement.html:

1 Use the @EnableTransactionManagement annotation on a @Configuration - annotated configuration class.

2 Set  in the Spring XML configuration.

But my Spring project neither has a @Configuration - annotated configuration class nor a Spring XML configuration.

Is there a way to enable transaction management in application.properties?

If the answer is no, then I'll have to go with 1 or 2 as stated above.

Thanks,
Andy

Comment: I am configuring my application with the application.properties file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no, you need to tell the container that it's going to use transaction.

> It is not sufficient to tell you simply to annotate your classes with
>   the @Transactional annotation, add @EnableTransactionManagement to
>   your configuration

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.